# Backbone pagination

Tags: rest, backbone.js, pagination, paginator

can anyone explain to me how this backbone.paginator example works?

```
https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator/blob/master/examples/request-paging/collections/PaginatedCollection.js
```

I see that the backend can be reached using the URL:

```
paginator_core: {
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/twitter/bootstrap/issues?'
},
```

But what/where does this example pass the page number and amount of itmes to retreive from the backend? My backend is accessible through the following restfull url: and i cant figure out how the next page details are inserted in the url above...

```
www.test.com/getItems/{query}/{from}/{size}
```

Is this automatically inserted by the paginator plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Just check internal implementation for fetch method

```
 // map params except directions
      var queryParams = this.mode == "client" ?
        _pick(this.queryParams, "sortKey", "order") :
        _omit(_pick(this.queryParams, _keys(PageableProto.queryParams)),
              "directions");

      var i, kvp, k, v, kvps = _pairs(queryParams), thisCopy = _clone(this);
      for (i = 0; i < kvps.length; i++) {
        kvp = kvps[i], k = kvp[0], v = kvp[1];
        v = _isFunction(v) ? v.call(thisCopy) : v;
        if (state[k] != null && v != null) {
          data[v] = state[k];
        }
      }
```

request creates based on

```
queryParams: {
  currentPage: "page",
  pageSize: "per_page",
  totalPages: "total_pages",
  totalRecords: "total_entries",
  sortKey: "sort_by",
  order: "order",
  directions: {
    "-1": "asc",
    "1": "desc"
  }
},
```

property - thus current collection state mapps over setting from queryParams for generations url